# Add returned orders to inventory

Tags: ee-1.13, stock

How to add returned products back to inventory?

If a customer orders a product it gets subtracted from the shops inventory. Now I would like to add it back if he returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a creditmemo the stock will be return to the inventory, depending on the used payment method you will have the option to specify if you want to return it to stock.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a Magento default option when creating a Credit Invoice?
On each product item row there is a checkbox to send the item back to stock.